# Deep link params are not passed through Mozilla Firefox and Opera to Android app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to open the app with created Deep link registered on the Firebase Deep Linking service. Alongside the original link, I am trying to pass some extra params to the app in order to process this link.

For example, I have a link: https://my-custom.page.link/page?page=place&id=1001126

The link https://my-custom.page.link/page is registered on the Firebase service and ?page=place&id=1001126 are custom params.

Since we are building a react-native app, this is working as expected on all browsers on the IOS application. On the Android application, it is working as expected on a Google browser but NOT on Firefox or Opera.

On the Android Firefox and Opera browsers when I click on the link it is redirected to my application but additional params are not passed to it.

Is there any other configuration that needs to be set for an Android project to fix this behavior?

After I log data returned from react-native Linking.getInitialURL() I got null.

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'


.
.
.

async componentDidMount () {
    const deepLinkUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL()
    console.warn('deepLinkUrl => ', deepLinkUrl) // IOS: correct payload Object, Android: null - Firefox and Opera
}
```

I expect to get correct data payload on both platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced similar issue while using Firebase Dynamic links.
Unfortunately I was not able to pass parameters from Mozilla and Opera browsers using this approach.

However I found hacky way of doing it.

If you use firebase react native package: `import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'`, it also has functionality for getting deep link url : `deepLinkUrl = await firebase.links().getInitialLink()`

Using this function you will get the App Store url from Firebase Dynamic Link. 
Idea is to pass your parameters through App Store url in the way that you encode parameters e.g `https://yourlink.page.link/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.yourapp%26param1%3Dvalue%26param2%3Dvalue...`

These parameters will be striped if user goes to the app store, and if the user opens the link in the app you will be able to extract parameters from this url.

I hope this answer helps. :)

Comment: Wow,  I spent hours to figure this out. Thanks for the answer. BTW my issue was opening the app from Android Gmail inbuild webview and I can fix it with this way.